# "Квелый" — этимология

Tags: этимология

"Квелый" — значит вялый, уставший, бессильный. А какова этимология этого слова? От какого оно произошло корня?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В словаре Даля есть КВОЛЫЙ от "КВЕЛИТЬ кого, яросл. ниж. вологодск. тамб. орл. твер. келить, арх. кялить, дразнить, сердить, доводить до слез, не давать покою, особ. дразнить ребенка. Не квели малого, и так вишь зарюмился. -ся, плакаться, жалобиться на все, плаксиво пенять; упрямиться, визжать, плакать. Ребенок квелит или квелится, хнычет или пищит. Квелый ряз. тамб. кволый южн. зап. квилкий арх. хилый, слабый, нежный, болезненный; болький, чувствительный; жалобный, писклявый, недотрога. Индюшка птица квелая. Он родом такой кволый; не работник. Квилкий веред у меня, не дает лечь." (веред=нарыв, гнойник).

М. Фасмер ссылается на Даля, но добавляет следующее: " Чередование *квьл-: * квол-;  Диал. квялый -- то же, донск., терск., возм., под влиянием вяґлый (Ильинский, РФВ 78, 204 и сл.)"

К слову КВЕЛИТЬ у Фасмера есть еще добавление: "... укр. квилiґти, чеш. kviґliti "рыдать, причитать, завывать, стонать", польск. kwilicґ "охать, стонать". 
   Получается, что корень КВЕЛ-